# HOW can I Achieve A Transparen Screen On My button Click Event In wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to show  A Panel on My Button Click Event And I want There is A transparent Screen Come between panel And other window Control . How CAN i Do it ? 
i m doing it all dynamic using C# not In xaml.

Thanks in Advance
shashank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a rectangle and set its opacity to the required value which will act as a transparent. Finally add your panel and this rectangle to the layout.

Comment: Hi veer 

Can u tell me about how much required value(opacity) is needed?

Comment: @SHASHANK: That depend on your requirement. `0` denotes complete transparency and `1` is opaque. You can set `0.6` for translucency.